# CSS relative div's width auto extend by absolute div

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to get parent (position: relative) auto extend its width by its absolute child? 
Here is my jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/YD2Xu/

The ideal is #container and #full-width should have the same width as #large-width.

CSS:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
#large-width, #full-width {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
}
#large-width {
    white-space: no-wrap;
    width: 1500px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#full-width {
    top: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="large-width">
        this is large width
    </div>
    <div id="full-width">
        this is full width
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to implement this by css, don't use javascript. Does anyone know how to do it?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't expand parent's div according to the child's size if child's position is absolute, because elements with absolute position are removed from the flow, so their size and even being are ignored by other elements including the parent. You can set fixed size with CSS or use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
overflow:auto;
```

for parent;

Comment: That constrains the visible area of the container, but doesn't really accomplish what the question asks. Provide more detail in your answer to explain your reasoning, so that even if this specific technique doesn't help answer the question, others will benefit from the discussion.